# Set up Mongodb and Python on Yocto Image

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, yocto, qemu

I am trying to set up python3 and mongodb package on my yocto build image.
The target machine is qemuarm64 as I am trying to set up a system for an ARM architecture.

I am using an AWS EC2 instance to set this up.

PFB my local.conf and bblayers.conf files and suggest what I might be doing wrong.

**bblayers.conf**
[image: bblayers.conf]

**local.conf-image1**
[image: local.conf-image1]

**local.conf-image2**
[image: local.conf-image3]

Regards,
Aarushi

Comment: What is the issue ?

Comment: I cannot find mongodb packages in the qemu emulator image

Answer (score 0):

Check for `IMAGE_INSTALL` final value with:

```bash
bitbake -e <image_recipe> | grep ^IMAGE_INSTALL=
```

I think the problem is here:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_APPEND
```

Make it:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append
```

Comment: Hi, IMAGE_INSTALL_append gives an error that gets removed when I use IMAGE_INSTALL_APPEND

Comment: `IMAGE_INSTALL_APPEND` is a new variable and has no effect with `IMAGE_INSTALL`, please provide the error with `IMAGE_INSTALL_append`.